# Mapping OAuth2 Login to custom Principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We are experimenting with Spring Security 5's new [OAuth 2.0 Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-oauth2login) feature. With the simple setup, Spring creates `Authentication` objects with a name matching the Id of the user in the OAuth 2.0 system. So if logging in with Google, `Authentication::getName()` returns a Google Id.

We want to use our own internal Ids and map from the OAuth2.0 provider's user Id's to our own user Ids. For example, we would take a Google user Id and use that to load our own Id. What is the correct way to do this?

We tried configuring the OIDC User Service as shown below.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(new MappingOidcUserService());
}
```

And then we can configure the value of `Authentication::getName()`. But this also changes the value of `OAuth2AuthorizedClient::getPrincipalName()` to our own Id. We want to be able to still get the external Id. And it's also a little concerning what other implications this could cause.